# flutter: Compiling for iOS 8.0, but module 'FBSDKCoreKit' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 9.0

Tags: facebook, flutter, dart

trying to deploy facebook sdk for my flutter app and using the facebook event package.
i followed the steps in the official link:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios
then the 4th step tried the step in the facebook events package link.
https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_app_events

adding this to my info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
  <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>fb[APP_ID]</string>
  </array>
  </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>[APP_ID]</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>[APP_NAME]</string>
```

when trying to build te app its gives error, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is the exact error that you're getting when you "build the app"? Could you please update your question with some Flutter doctor output and build logs please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a global platform for your project.

Open ios/Podfile

You might be seeing this in the first two line of the file

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
```

You need to remove the **#** from the second line and need to make the build again. If fails then please try **flutter clean** and try again

Here are the final first two lines of ios/Podfile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
```

Comment: compiling for iOS 8.0, but module 'FBSDKCoreKit' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 9.0: